# How to save and return a file

Tags: image, postgresql, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm trying to save an image to a database with sinatra-activerecord to be returned later. Currently (I think) saving is functioning correctly:

```
Photo.create(photo:params[:image][:tempfile].read)
```

But when I try to return it the browser shows a not an image icon, and when I actually go to the url that the browser is going to I see a mess of random characters. How can I get this to work and why isn't what I have working?

Here is how I am trying to return it:

```
file = Tempfile.new('photo')
file.write(Photo.find(params[:id]).photo)
return file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe you didn't know this already @thesecretmaster, it's obvious that you should have been saving the submitted `content-type` (`params[:image][:type]`) and then when you `return file` you should have set `content_type <previously saved content-type>` before retuning the stored binary image. Also, in case you weren't already doing this, you have to store `params[:image][:tempfile].read` with the type binary in activerecord, or you might get some variety of `AttributteError`.